Is it physically plausible for a universe to have global distance dilation/contraction relative to a parallel universe?
In the video game Minecraft, one can go through a portal from the overworld to the "parallel world" called the nether. If one starts at a point $A$ in the overworld, takes a portal to the nether, travels distance $d$, and then takes a portal back to the overworld, they will be a distance of $8d$ from point $A$. Obviously we are not aware of any such portals or parallel worlds in real life, but I'm wondering just how physically plausible/implausible it would be.
A bit more formally, I'm wondering if it's it plausible to have two "universes" (3D spatial manifolds?) that satisfy the following conditions:

There is a bijective mapping between points on these manifolds.
If two points in manifold A are a given distance apart, the corresponding points in manifold B are ~1 order of magnitude closer.
These manifolds are "close" to one another in higher dimensional space, such that the length of a wormhole between two corresponding points is manageable for a human to traverse in a reasonable amount of time.
Each manifold doesn't need to be globally euclidian, but should be approximately euclidian such that a human would not easily notice any non-euclidian aspects of it.
The manifolds don't necessarily need to be infinite, but should be effectively infinite relative to a human scale.
The formation of the wormholes doesn't need to be explained since I don't think we have such an explanation, but given that they exist they should be geometrically plausible.

One popular explanation is that these manifolds are each on the surface of concentric hyperspheres, and the nether's hypersphere is 1/8th the size of the overworld's. This works fairly well, but breaks down because the distance that a wormhole would have to cover is ~1/6th the size of the overworld, since you would have to travel from the surface of the hypersphere to nearly the center of it. Assuming that the overworld is large, that would take a very long time. If we want to traverse that distance in a short time, it would involve fatal acceleration/deceleration.
Another explanation is that they are fractal spaces similar to a space filling curve, but in higher dimensions. For example, let's assume that the overworld is a 1D space that follows iteration $n$ of a hilbert curve, and the nether follows iteration $n-3$. If $n$ is arbitrarily large, the distance between corresponding points between can be arbitrarily small. However, if we take this analogy to 3 dimensions and choose $n$ such that the maximum wormhole length is small on a human scale, then I think a human would notice significant curvature that results in a non-euclidian space.
Another explanation might be that my mindset is too euclidian, and less-euclidian explanations are trivially plausible. Perhaps "wormhole" is not well defined, and it's possible that the "length" of a wormhole as perceived by a human can be short despite covering a longer distance. Or similarly, maybe it's possible to just say that space is 1/8th as dense in the nether relative to the overworld.
Is there a plausible explanation, or is this whole premise implausible enough that it's not worth searching for a explanation in our understanding of physics?

I'm aware of the no-fictional-physics rule, so I tried to make this as physically grounded as I could. Feel free to close if you think it's still too fictional.

That actually bears some resemblance to warped 5D geometry models like Randall-Sundrum.

Brane worlds?
